# problems with cut (unix)

Tags: unix, scripting, csh, tcsh

I've got strange problem with `cut` 
I wrote script, there I have row:

```
... | cut -d" " -f3,4 >! out
```

cut recieves this data (I checked it with echo)

```
   James             James              033333333 0              0.00
```

but I recieve empty lines in `out`, can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compress out the sequences of spaces, so that each string of spaces is replaced by a single space. The [`tr` command's](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) -s (squeeze) option is perfect for this:

```
$ ... | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f3,4 >! out
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want fields from a text file, `awk` is almost always the answer:

```
... | awk '{print $3" "$4}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo 'James     James      033333333 0              0.00' | cut -d" " -f3,4

$ echo 'James     James      033333333 0              0.00' | awk '{print $3" "$4}'
033333333 0
```

Comment: oh, can I do it without awk, I can't use it, it is part of my project, I do it only with cut, grep, sort, uniq, head, tail

Comment: None of those commands will compress multiple spaces into one. Are you sure it's not tabs in the input?

Comment: yes, I'm sure, but still how can I do it without awk, I don't have fixed spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Cut doesn't see multiple spaces as single space, so it matches "nothingness" between spaces.

Do you get empty lines when you leave out  `>! out` part? Ie, are you targeting correct fields?

If your input string uses fixed spacing, you might want to use `cut -c 4-10,15-20 | tr -d ' '` to extract character groups 4-10 and 15-20 and remove spaces from them..

Comment: yes of course, 5 elements, but I didn't know about nothingness, how can I change it I need 4th and 5th fields?

Comment: You could use another form of cut (see my edited post), or you could use awk (see next answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
... | grep -o "[^ ]*"
```

will extract fields, each on separate line. Then you might head/tail them. Not sure about putting them on the same line again.